# md5 в Python и PHP не совпадают суммы

Tags: php, python, md5

Нахожу md5 от json в php

```
$data =  ['key1'=> 'value1', 'key2'=> 'value2'];
$key = 'key';
echo md5(json_encode($data).$key);
```

Получаю 07f62bada07fee33ce3797465a7d8197

[код](https://ideone.com/lxTGfa)

Делаю тоже самое в python

```
import json
import hashlib
 
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
 
k = 'key'.encode()
y = json.dumps(payload).encode()
m = hashlib.md5(y+k).hexdigest()
print(m)
```

Получаю 968d4b64e6859dd0f1c725078e957652

[код](https://ideone.com/lDvdGI)

Что только не перепробовал. Результат всегда разный.
Единственное если просто строку подставить, тогда результат одинаковый.

Comment: Всё правильно, json'ы не обязаны кодироваться абсолютно одинаково

Comment: есть подозрение, что сами строки у вас тоже не идентичны

Comment: Но как быть если нужно сделать проверку на безопасность. И сравнить эти хеши.

Comment: Использовать вместо json что-нибудь более предсказуемое, можно даже свою собственную функцию кодирования написать. Или можно попробовать поиграться с опциями кодирования json (они есть и в php, и в python), но это менее надёжно и добиться совпадения на некоторых граничных случаях будет не очень просто

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Долго ломал голову пока чуть-ли не в каждой строке писал `print` и смотрел что выводит.
если вывести

```
print(json.dumps(payload).encode())
```

и всмотреться в результат в консоли

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то видны три лишних пробела.
после того как их убрать, например так

```
y = json.dumps(payload).replace(' ', '').encode()
```

результат

```
m = hashlib.md5(y+k).hexdigest()
```

будет

```
07f62bada07fee33ce3797465a7d8197
```

**UPD**

[используйте](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

```
y = json.dumps(payload, separators=(',', ':')).encode()
```

для удаления пробелов